# In Edsger Dijkstra's quote, meaning of 'the plague'

Tags: meaning-in-context, quotes

> "The competent programmer is fully aware of the limited size of his own skull. He therefore approaches his task with full humility, and avoids clever tricks like the plague." [[EWD340](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD340.html)]

I am trying to understand this quote of Edsger W. Dijkstra. I understand that he emphasize to be a good programmer. However, I don't understand the meaning of 'the plague'. General meaning of 'the plague' is ill, but this context says it couldn't be.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***"Avoid like the plague"*** is an idiom which means to ignore or keep away from someone or something totally..

Refer http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/avoid+like+the+plague

Comment: This readily-available, intuitive, and fully correct answer indicates that the question probably could have been (and perhaps should have been) asked on [ell.se]. The O.P. might want to see if that would be a good site to use for future questions.

Comment: And the phrase is more than a little cliched to the point that you don't see it much in professional literature anymore.

Answer (score 3):

It means the programmer avoids clever tricks like he avoids the plague. The elision of the second "avoids" is quite natural in English.

So "the plague" is a reference to the literal plague.

Comment: There is the faintly possible ambiguity with the 'such as' sense: _He avoids writing essays on epidemics like the plague._

Comment: @Edwin: I suppose if we look at it from [Yersinia pestis's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yersinia_pestis) point of view (that being the relevant bacterium), it *might* be possible to see [the (bubonic) plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubonic_plague) as a "clever trick". But actually it hasn't worked out so well for those bugs in the long run - they might be hanging on better than smallpox, but they're not much of a threat to us today compared to all sorts of "inter-species" viruses.

Comment: "Literal" is misleading. A competent programmer does *not* avoid clever ideas by killing rats and spraying fleas. At most you could say it's a metaphor, if not an idiom.

Comment: @GregHullender I reject your conclusion. *Like* here obviously means "as vehemently as" not "using the same methods as", so *literal* is quite correct.

Comment: Well, here in America, the average programmer makes no effort at all to avoid the plague. Perhaps things are different in your place of work. ;-)

Comment: @Greg Hullender Surely all idioms **reference** some literal event etc (if only second or third hand)? Agreed that plague-avoidance measures are hardly likely to be meant literally here.

Comment: Well, how about "kick the bucket"? :-)

Comment: The article at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kick_the_bucket has several theories on the origin of the phrase; all involve a material 'bucket' of some kind. The fact that the actual referent may no longer be unequivocally identifiable does not prove that there wasn't one.

Answer (score 1):

The Black Plague (also called the Bubonic Plague, or Black Death) decimated medieval Europe back in the mid 1300s.  Estimates run up to 200 million dead, which is a lot for the mid 1300s. (It was caused by a bacillus, carried by fleas, which came on rats, which arrived on boats.  It was perhaps the nastiest thing ever to hit human-kind.

So naturally, it was something you should completely avoid.

Dijkstra wrote that back in the 50s [more or less]. Unfortunately, since then, it has become an overworked cliche - a phrase that has seen better days.

One set of the Rules Of Grammar has "Avoid cliches like the plague".

I don't think he meant that clever tricks were like the plague, but rather, that you should not use "clever tricks" at all.  Clever tricks, in programming, will almost cause terrible headaches for people who have to update the program later on.

Comment: +1 ...he meant ...that you should not use "clever tricks" at all.